# Is it dangerous to install a covered exterior outlet without a junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I installed a GFCI outlet in an outdoor stucco wall without a box. The outlet is protected by a weather box

Answer (score 17):

It violates code and it is dangerous.

The GFCI effectively protects the *output* - i.e., the two receptacles and the "load" terminals, at least from anything that would create a ground fault, which includes many of the effects of water and other things, but it doesn't protect from everything. Plus the GFCI itself can be damaged by water and other things because it is a much more complex device than a simple receptacle.

However, the "line" terminals are totally unprotected if the device is not installed in a proper box. A proper box protects against:

- Bugs (coming from the outside to the device and getting zapped)
- Loose wires (from the device going to the outside and providing zapping opportunities for mice and men
- Water, dirt, etc. from getting into the device - not 100% but generally pretty well

In *some* cases the box is there for structural reasons, and arguably your stucco wall may take care of that quite well. But a hole in a stucco wall does not adequately protect against all the other possible problems.

A proper box also either includes integral clamps or allows for the addition of clamps. Cables *must* be clamped as otherwise if the other end of the cable is pulled the wire connections to the device could be affected. Wires in conduits don't get clamps because they are protected by conduit, but you definitely don't want conduit opening up into some random space in stucco.

Most important of all, a proper box will protect against arcing and fires. A metal box will protect the best, but even a plastic box will do a fairly good job - they are designed and tested to take care of a limited amount of arcing. Stucco isn't. And stucco isn't even necessarily all stucco - there can be layers of insulation and other materials.

**Remove the GFCI/receptacle. Cut a big enough hole for a nice metal box. Install the box. Reinstall the GFCI/receptacle.**

Comment: This is why modern codes prefer GFCI circuit breakers...

Comment: Note that even if this were an internal installation, putting a receptacle in the wall without a box is dangerous and a code violation.

Comment: I am going to fix it. But the best answer was from the guy that said it is somewhat dangerous. There is a good amount of caulking around the weather box so no bugs can enter. And arcing is not very likely as I tightened the wires with care. Still it is a code violation and I will fix it.

Comment: @user106218 "tightened the wires with care", or with the torque specified by the manufacturer?

Comment: "And stucco isn't even necessarily all stucco - there can be layers of insulation and other materials." - such as a metal mesh.

Comment: You use a torque wrench to wire an outlet?

Comment: @user106218 In theory, yes. In reality, most people (electricians or not, but almost anyone who isn't, because hardly anyone who just replaces an occasional receptacle or switch has a torque driver) don't. I actually think it is much less relevant when used on screw-to-clamp - you just make it as tight as practical. With regular screw terminals there are more issues - at least in my non-engineer, non-NEC opinion. There are some Wago-style connectors on some receptacles now - that's a way to totally avoid the problem.